# Branding per site collection with same feature

Tags: 2010, site-collection, branding

I have 2 site collections.
I am using same feature to deploy branding.
Is there a way that i can deploy my solution in one site collection without affecting the another one ?
Except creating new features.

Comment: Each Site Collection is independent. If you have your styles in the site collection style library you shouldn't have problems

Comment: but my master page gets affected as feature are same for both sites.

Comment: you only could edit the master page with designer. The only problem is when you deactivate and activate the feature probably the master page will be overwritten again.

Comment: @Alvmad: I have to deploy my solution through powershell script. and also features need to be reactivated.